# PHP interesting creation of the class instance

Tags: php, syntax

I've read about this interesting syntax in PHP:

```
$value = (new MyClass)->attribute1;
```

1. Is it ok to use it? I've never seen anything like this in any code I've analyzed. Any pros and cons?
2. Why can't I set the attribute using this syntax? Structures like this:

   (new MyClass)->attribute1 = 'value1';

throw errors at '=' sign, no matter if the attribute exists in the class already.

Comment: That syntax is valid since php version 5.4 according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Well i don't see the point of using it since you loose your reference to the object, you cannot use it anymore, and it breaks the OO concept.
2. I think (new MyClass)->attribute1 is resolved first, so it is the same as writing something like 42 = 12

Answer (score 0):

This may have a sense, if the class `MyClass` supports internal static list (or hashmap) of all existing instances. This way you can create new object and get its unique ID or index in the list for future references (for example, by sending it via cookies to a client).

As for assignment, you'd post exact error message for this case. I can guess, that the error is about assigning something to a temporary value which is about to be destroyed.